# How to add Jquery Hover Effect to Wordpress in functions/header/footer

Tags: jquery, wordpress

My problem is that I put my jQuery code in my `functions.php` file and the code pulls my stylesheet but doesn't pull my jquery effect (sliding effect) what could be the problem?

Comment: Why would you put jQuery code in functions.php? Put it in a javascript file and use wp_enque_script to load it.

Comment: Got it to work! I was missing one line of code. Thanks it worked!!!